# SQL MERGE: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
merge into emp_tar.et
    using emp_src.es on (et.emp_id, es.emp_id)
insert into (et.emp_id,et.emp_name)
    values(es.emp_id,es.emp_name)
```

Whenever I execute this code it gives the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ','

Comment: What are you trying to do here...?  There are multiple problems with your code.

Comment: You should start by looking at the documentation for MERGE. What you posted here has so many syntax errors it is obvious you have not looked at any examples. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here is the right `Merge` syntax

```
Merge into emp_tar et
    using emp_src es on et.emp_id = es.emp_id -- use = to equate two columns
When Not Matched then -- to insert the records only it is not present in target 
insert into (et.emp_id,et.emp_name)
    values(es.emp_id,es.emp_name)
```

Which is same as

```
Insert into emp_tar(emp_id,emp_name)
Select es.emp_id,es.emp_name 
From emp_src es 
Where Not exists (select 1 from emp_tar et Where et.emp_id = es.emp_id)
```

`Merge` statement can be used when you want to perform more than one DML operation. Also `Merge` in Sql Server is quite buggy better to use `Insert from Select` in your case

**[Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)**

Comment: thanks please tell me the same with destructive merge and append.